# Chrome - nth-child rule is too slow

Tags: css, google-chrome, css-selectors, pseudo-class

I've been testing DOM selecting performance using jQuery. 
I get some questions after comparing $("ul li:nth-child(999)") to $("ul li").eq(999)

```
$("ul li:nth-child(999)");
$("ul li").eq(999);
```

Please click on the following link to see my detailed test results :

[JSPerf Test Result](http://jsperf.com/nth-child-vs-last-child-vs-eq-with-element-1000)

Especially Chrome shows poor performance for operating nth-child pseudo classes.
 
I want to know why such a result is caused. 
Can I get any algorithm, mechanism or references about that?

I would be very grateful if someone helps me.
Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I couldn't find any answer about this question anywhere, think that it can be an unknown bug.
So I sent an email to Chromium Team, this issue has been ticketed on Chromium forum officially.

You can see the ticket for nth-child issue on the following link :

https://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=364081&q=nth&colspec=ID%20Pri%20M%20Iteration%20ReleaseBlock%20Cr%20Status%20Owner%20Summary%20OS%20Modified

Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

Your testing result is interesting. I also hope to know the correct answer to differences in the algorithm at the base.

Not talking about the algorithms of the two functions, I do not know if that helps.
But I think just functionally...

First, the two functions are slightly different.

`$().eq` is the **jQuery method**. It's own jQuery method.
A little differently, `':nth-child'` is **CSS selector**. It's passed to jQuery Engine optimized for nearly the performance as the CSS engine.

And these two things are functionally different.

According to [CSS3 :nth-child() Selector](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/sel_nth-child.asp),

> The :nth-child(n) selector matches every element that is **the nth child**, regardless of type, **of its parent**.

and
[jQuery eq() Method](https://www.w3schools.com/jquery/traversing_eq.asp),

> The eq() method returns an element with **a specific index number** of the selected elements.

For example,

```
<body>
    <div> div 1 </div>
    <div> div 2 </div>
    <div> div 3 </div>
    <div>
        div 4
        <div> div 5</div>
        <div> div 6</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

If you use `$('body div').eq(2)`, it return the jQuery object for `<div> div 2 </div>` depending on the index 2.
Else if you use `$('body div:nth-child(2)')`, it return the set of jQuery objects for `<div> div 2 </div>` **'and `<div> div 6 </div>`'**.

Because it the 'nth-child(n)' css selector return the nth child of **'its parent'**.

But I also don't what the underlying cause that makes **eq() method** is slower than another.
I'm sorry if it did not help.